# How to open a some questions in a new tab?

Tags: support, mathjax, titles

From a list of questions one could right-click and choose "open in new tab" in Chrome/Mozilla. But when the title of the equation is an equation, and only an equation, only a MathJax popup shows up. How can I open these questions in a new tab?

Comment: Related: [near duplicate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204/mathjax-menu-obliterates-link-menu-when-the-entire-link-is-latex), [another near duplicate](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8695/cannot-open-question-that-contains-only-formulas), and [another one](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/8891/title-and-latex). Finally, [related guidelines post](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9687/guidelines-for-good-use-of-latex-in-question-titles).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In most browsers, you can press Ctrl while clicking a link to open it in a new tab.

Comment: Middle-click is also fairly standard.